# validating form entries before allowing to submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Please help: New to this and I can't figure this out.

Creating a registration form for a website where user has to register an account inputting their; 
First Name, 
LastName
Email address
Password and enter password again to ensure that they match. 
before form can be submitted.  code must check all fields to see that all fields have been populated. Only after filling out all fields and password matches then user can register.

If they click the button before filling out all fields they should be advised that fields are required.

Nothing is happening when I run the code.

This is what I have.

```
$ (function(){
    $('.btn').on('click'(function(){
        validateFormFName();
        validateFormLName();
        validateFormEmail();
        password();
    });
});

function validateFormFName() {
    var x = document.form["formtype"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateFormLName() {
    var x = document.form["formtype"]["lname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateFormEmail() {
    var x = document.form["formtype"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Your email is required");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


function password() {
    if (document.getElementById('psw1').value ==
        document.getElementById('psw2').value) {
        document.getElementById('register').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help].  Can you tell us what is going wrong?  Please edit your question with any errors you're seeing and/or a description of what should happen vs. what's actually happening.  That way we're not debugging your code blind.  Also, could you include your HTML? Thanks!

Comment: @JBH thanks I have updated question. Nothing is happening when I run the code. The error doesn't show that the fields are mandatory and they must be filled in.

Comment: Let's see your HTML, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't know if I understood your question, but I will try help you.

If I understand correctly these can help you.

```
$ (function(){
    $('.btn').on('click'(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        validateFormFName();
        validateFormLName();
        validateFormEmail();
        password();
    });
});
```

If I was wrong let me know, I will try improve my answer.

Comment: hey. I am trying to validate the fields on registration form created for a website. The user must fill out all fields before allowed to register. If they leave a field empty and click the register button should be advised that eg. "Name field is mandatory please enter name" . Also, when entering their password both fields password enter in both fields must match. If they do not match then they should be told that "Password does not match"..Hope I explained it better.

Comment: Yes I understood the same, So my conclusion is you don`t get the error message, because your form are being submitted, so you need stop the default behavior.